# Dynamically change overlay images to a streaming video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am stuck in a situation where I need to dynamically change overlays for a streaming video. I am able to change overlay images specifying a time but I dont know on hand when I need to change the overlay image.

I need to keep changing the image overlay dynamically when a overlay image is created without interrupting the streaming. How can this be achieved.

Any suggestion.